# How to use lucene SpanQuery in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

For my project, I thought of using Span Near Queries of ElasticSearch, with the constraint that is, certain tokens may have to searched with Fuzziness. I was able to generate a set of SpanQuery (org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanQuery) objects some with fuzzy enabled, some without. I couldn't figure out how to use these set of SpanQueries in ElasticSearch spanNearQuery.

Can someone help me out with right pointers to samples or docs. And is there any way to construct ES SpanNearQueryBuilder with some clauses fuzzy enabled ?

Comment: I don't see any need for downvoting, as I had asked this question, after putting in decent amount of efforts. When are we going to stop discouraging people to ask right questions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap an fuzzy query into a span query with [Span Multi Term Query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-span-multi-term-query.html):

```
{
    "span_near" : {
        "clauses" : [
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "value1" } },
            { "span_multi" : 
                "match" : {
                    "prefix" : { "user" :  { "field" : "value2" } }
                }
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```